# Identify input and output parameters in stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

If I have a stored procedure containing input and output parameters, is it possible to access this information some how? What I would like is a list identifying the parameters and whether they are input or output.

Comment: I just "discovered" sp_sproc_columns. Seems like it might be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT name, 
       is_output
FROM sys.parameters
WHERE object_id=object_id('dbo.YourProc')
```

Comment: Thank you Martin. Your answer let me to the sp_sproc_columns SP which provided the information I required.

Answer (score 0):

[sys.parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176074.aspx) is a table containing such information (e.g. the `is_output` column)